# Rails: model.validate - wrong number of argument

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

i'm new to ruby on rails and I am trying to create a custom message for a model's validation failure scenario. Here is the code.

```
class TestModel
    include ActiveModel::Model
    attr_accessor :attr
    validates :attr, presence: true,
         format: {with:  /\A[A-Za-z].+\z/,
         message: -> (value) do
            # Do something with value
         end
            }       
end

model = TestModel.new
model.attr = 23242
model.validate
```

However i receive the error

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)
```

I was following a similar example on the [ruby on rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html) : section 3.3. There is something wrong with defining the message as I have.

I'm using rails 5.
Also, what i want to do with value is get the inverse REGEX.

```
"contains invalid char(s) " + 
    value.split('').reject{ 
        |e| /\A[A-Za-z].+\z/ =~ e }.join(' ')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're going to use a lambda with the `:message` option then your lambda will get *two* arguments. From the [fine guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#message):

> **3.3 :message**
>   [...]
>   A Proc :message value is given two arguments: the object being validated, and a hash with `:model`, `:attribute`, and `:value` key-value pairs.

So you'd say:

```
message: -> (model, data) do
  # Do something with model and data here...
end
```

And from [section 2.5](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#format):

> **2.5 format**
>   [...]
>   Alternatively, you can require that the specified attribute does *not* match the regular expression by using the `:without` option.

If you want the opposite of `:with` then use `:without` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You're not using `message` correctly. You don't need to pass it a block to interpolate the value. Use it like so.

```
require 'active_model'
class TestModel
  include ActiveModel::Model
  attr_accessor :attr
  validates :attr, 
            presence: true,
            format: {with:  /\A[A-Za-z].+\z/,
            message: "#{value} is wrong" }
end

model = TestModel.new
model.attr = 23242
puts model.validate # false 
puts model.errors.full_messages # Attr 23242 is wrong
```

Yes, it's `%{value}` and not `#{value}`

If you do want to use a proc, it accepts two arguments.

Comment: But sometimes you do need to use pass a proc or lambda with `:message`, for example, the message might depend on runtime locale information or other properties of the model instance.